# How do you read the coq quantifier `forall P: Set -> Prop`?

Tags: types, coq, proof, theorem-proving

I'm brand new to Coq and working through Mike Nahas's tutorial here: [nahas_tutorial.v](https://github.com/coq/www/blob/master/files/nahas_tutorial.v). Specifically, I'm having trouble understanding the statement given below:

```
Theorem forall_exists : (forall P : Set -> Prop,  (forall x, ~(P x)) -> ~(exists x, P x)).
```

Here's my interpretation so far, corrections welcome.

The statement `Set -> Prop` is a proposition which can be expanded to `forall s: Set, Prop` which I understand as "for every proof (read instance) of a `Set`, we also have a proof (instance) of a `Prop`".

Thus `forall P : Set -> Prop` can be roughly read as "for every proof that a set gives rise to a proposition".

Then for `(forall x, ~(P x))`, my guess is that `x` is inferred to be of type `Set` by Coq, and that it's read as "every set gives rise to an unprovable/false proposition".

And for `~(exists x, P x)`, I read that as there exist no sets which imply the existence of a true proposition under P.

These seem logically equivalent. I'm just struggling with the language. Can `P` be interpreted as a function which maps from the space of sets to the space of propositions? I've used the phrases "give rise to" and "imply existence of"; is this correct? Is there a more correct way to state this?

Thanks for any and all assistance!

EDIT: For anyone who has a similar question, my confusion mostly amounted to an ignorance of the Curry-Howard isomorphism.

My interpretation (perhaps still a bit shaky) is now that the theorem reads "For every predicate (boolean-valued function) `P` ranging over elements of type `Set`, if the image of every set under `P` is false, then there's no set for which `P` yields `True`."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set -> Prop` belongs to `Type`, not `Prop`. When you're in `Type`, `X -> Y` should be read as a function from `X` to `Y`, and when you're in `Prop`, it should be read as `X` implies `Y` (though by Curry-Howard these are the same).

When a function returns a `Prop` it's usually considered a predicate or a property.  So `forall P : Set -> Prop` can be read as "for every `Set`-valued property..."

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. So just to clarify, is it true that anything on the right-hand side of the colon in a statement like `forall a: b` is in `Type`? Is the interpretation of the colon in that statement the same as in the vernacular line above, so we'd read that the theorem `forall_exists` is of type `(forall P : Set -> Prop,  (forall x, ~(P x)) -> ~(exists x, P x))`, i.e. it's a proof of that statement?

Comment: Yes everything to the right of a colon is in `Type` (or `Prop` or `Set`) but those are subtypes of `Type`.  And yes, declaring `Theorem`'s, `Definition`'s, and `Lemma`'s are all essentially the same thing:  declaring some term of a certain type.

Comment: I disagree: `Set -> Prop` is the type of a function whose arguments are in `Set` and whose values are in `Prop`.  So it would rather be `Prop`-valued, which is already expressed by saying it is a predicate.  I would prefer that you say that an object `P` of type `Set -> Prop` is a predicate ranging over elements of type `Set`, which is a type of types.  An example of such a predicate could be `finite`, expressing that a given type is finite, and `finite nat` would not hold, while `finite bool` would hold, with a proper definition of `finite`.